# Trying to loop through UIView and all subviews to get the first responder, not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, first-responder

I am trying to find the current focused `First Responder` by looping through the main `UIView` and all of it's `SubViews`, and all of it's `SubViews` through recursion, but I am coming up with `nil`.

```
extension UIView {
func getCurrentFirstResponder() -> AnyObject? {
    if self.isFirstResponder() {
        return self
    }

    for subView: UIView in self.subviews as [UIView] {
        if subView.isFirstResponder() {
            return subView
        }
        else {
            subView.getCurrentFirstResponder()
        }
    }
    return nil
}
}

let focusedView = self.view.getCurrentFirstResponder() as? UIView
```

Does this look correct? Why am I getting a `nil` view when I use this?

Comment: I think one thing you should know is that `UIViewController` is  also in the responder chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for subView: UIView in self.subviews as [UIView] {
    if subView.isFirstResponder() {
        return subView
    }
    else {
        if let sub = subView.getCurrentFirstResponder() {
           return sub;
        }
    }
}
return nil
```

Answer (score 2):

You code doesn't return anything in case the recursive call to `subView.getCurrentFirstResponder()` actually finds a first responder.